# Sharing Java packages between modules in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, package

I'm trying to figure out how can I share packages between two modules in a single IntelliJ project, and I can't seem to find the right way to do it. I know it can be done in Eclipse, but I'm not very well-versed with it. In a nutshell, I'm trying to reproduce the same kind of project environment created by AppEngine-connected Android projects.

Here's the "problem" as best I can lay it out

Project A.

- Module 1; AppEngine + GWT + whatever else
- Module 2; Android

Each module has its own source directory within the Project's main directory:

- /ProjectA/Module1/src
- /ProjectA/Module2/src

I create packages for both modules, and write the various classes needed for each. Most classes are unique to the module / platform, and are packaged into their own namespace

Module 1

- com.example.myproject.server
- com.example.myproject.server.domain
- com.example.myproject.server.services
- ...

Module 2

- com.example.myproject.client
- com.example.myproject.client.activities
- com.example.myproject.client.fragments
- ...

However, there are some identical Interfaces and Enums that I use within both modules: Now I'd like to have all my identical code in a single package shared between the two, so I don't have to copy the source between packages every time I change something around.

- com.example.myproject.shared
- com.example.myproject.shared.interfaces
- ...

I know IntelliJ will allow you to configure multiple content Roots as part of a module's configuration. But it doesn't seem that two modules care share the same content root if their part of the same IntelliJ Project...? Is there a better way to configure my project? Or am I missing something..?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could move shared code into another module that has its own content root, say:

```
/ProjectA/Module3/src
```

and then add a module dependency on Module3 to both Module1 and Module2.

Comment: * **head-desk** * didn't even consider a third module... worked like a charm! Thanks!!

Comment: I have tried this solution and it did not work with GWT compilation. It worked only for server code.