# Import/use code from an other Intellij project

Tags: java, import, intellij-idea

I have two Intellij projects and in one of them I want to use some classes from the other. I'm not interested in making a library, because I want both projects to update if I change the code in the shared classes.

I have tried with modules, libraries and dependencies, but it won't work.

Thank you.

EDIT:
Followed the answer, this still doesn't. Picture show dependencies.

[image]

Comment: How did it not work? You should be able to get it working with modules. Did you set up the module dependencies?

Comment: Yeah, I set dependencies both my other project, packages, classes. Neither worked. Might be something little I do wrong, but that's why I need the current way step by step.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is the step you're missing.

Suppose `Project_B` depends on `Project_A`. To make one module depend on another

1. open the "Project Structure" dialog
2. click on the module that will have the the dependency
3. click the "Dependencies" tab
4. click the "+" (it's platform dependent as to exactly where it's located)
5. click "Module Dependency..."
6. when the dialog opens, click on the project to depend on

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, did exactly that, but still won't let me use the classes from the other. Added a picture to my question, take a look. I want to use a class from Chat, in the Tomcat project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you want but it is possible to share these files using some sort of version control.

Personally I recommend Git, it's reliable and easy enough to use.
You could use commits, push and pull to sync your files.

for more info on git: http://github.com

**EDIT:** I found a question on stack overflow that might be able to answer yours:
[Sharing Java packages between modules in IntelliJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425966/sharing-java-packages-between-modules-in-intellij)

This user made a third module and put the shared data in that, and then linked the third one to the first two. Maybe if you set it up like this it will work for you.

Comment: The projects are already on git, but not really what I'm after. You could do this in Eclipse, so probably it's possible in Intellij too.